# How can I display some records with twho conditions from different columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this code:

```
select
to_char(sysdate -0.25,'DAY') day,
t.task_id,
NVL (pu.part_id, 'NONE') part_id,
p.part_type,
t.request_id,
(select(concat(concat (p.first_name, ' '), p.last_name)) from person p where t.person_id = 
p.person_id) name,
pu.quantity,
to_number(pu.user_def15, '9999999.99') lunch,
to_char(cast(t.actual_start_dttm as timestamp) at time zone 'US/Eastern', 'HH24:MI') started,
to_char(cast(t.actual_end_dttm as timestamp) at time zone 'US/Eastern', 'HH24:MI') ended,
NVL(pu.user_def2, 'MISSING') description,
case when NVL(pu.user_def2, 'MISSING') = 'MISSING' then '#FF0000' else '#000000' end description_c,
t.task_status,
to_char(cast(t.plan_start_dttm as timestamp) at time zone 'US/Eastern', 'YYYY-MM-DD') start_date,
to_char (sysdate-0.25,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI') today
from task t 
LEFT JOIN part_usage pu ON t.task_id = pu.task_id LEFT JOIN part p ON pu.part_id = p.part_id
where 

t.access_group = 'CAPCA'
and to_char(cast(t.plan_start_dttm as timestamp) at time zone 'US/Eastern', 'YYYY-MM-DD') =
CASE WHEN
to_char(sysdate - 0.25,'DAY') = 'MÅNDAG '
THEN
 to_char (sysdate-3.25, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
ELSE
 to_char (sysdate-1.25, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
END
order by name, started
```

and here are my results on an excel export:

[image]
In my code, at the 4th line, I have an NVL that writes 'NONE' if there is no record and at the 12th a NVL that write a 'MISSING'.
The problem is because it's an NVL it happens only if there's no result at all.
I need to get the same result if no result is found with part_type as 'LABOR'
So in this example in the picture of the excel sheet, the line number 3 that has 'CONS' as part_type should display as lines  2,5, and 15 because there are no 'LABOR' results.
Thank you.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question exactly, but you can write things like `CASE WHEN pu.part_id IS NULL OR p.part_type<>'LABOR' THEN 'None' ELSE pu.part_id END` or, alternatively, `CASE WHEN part_type<>'LABOR' THEN 'NONE' ELSE NVL(pu.part_id, 'NONE') END` in your SELECT statement.

Comment: @ EdmCoff in both cases, I get a "incompatible character set".

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. What character set are your part_type and part_id columns? Is this part of a larger, UNIONed query?

Comment: @EdmCoff running this, SELECT *
  FROM v$nls_parameters
 WHERE parameter LIKE '%CHARACTERSET' I get this:
parameter value
NLS_CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16